# C#: HttpListener request InputStream is always an empty stream

Tags: c#, winforms, httplistener

I am trying to build a very simple web server with C#. I used `HttpListener` and so far i got it up and running. But when i try to get `InputStream` of request, i always encounter `NullStream`, no matter what i put in `GET`.

Here is my code:

```
class WebServer
{
    private HttpListener listener;
    private bool firstRun = true;
    private const string prefixes = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/";

    public void Start()
    {
        if (firstRun)
        {
            listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add(prefixes);
            firstRun = false;
        }
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException hlex)
        {
            return;
        }
        while (listener.IsListening)
        {
            var context = listener.GetContext();
            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;//i even tried to reset stream position 
            var body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();//this is always empty("")

            byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ACK");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = b.Length;

            var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            context.Response.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(body);
        }
        listener.Stop();
        listener.Close();
    }

}
```

To create a `GET` request i open browser and enter this URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/?samad=11`

as you can see in the code i also tried to reset stream position to its beginning, but still no luck.

Comment: Your browser doesnt send anything in the actual inputstream when simply opening the page. All data is located in the header. You might want to write a simple client that uses HttpWebRequest class in order to receive some data.

Comment: @CSharpie thank you for your comment. but what i want is to receive data that is typed in URL. i don't want to have a client program. i also checked `context.Request.Headers` and it didn't have `samad=11` data.

Comment: `samad=11` is in the QueryString, not the headers

Comment: @samadmontazeri you should include that in your question then.

Comment: @KevinGosse Yes. it is. thanks. i think i can do something with that.

Comment: You might be able to save yourself some headache by simply using Grapevine - a simple, embeddable REST/HTTP server build using HttpListener. https://sukona.github.io/Grapevine/en/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** This answers a question from the comments, not the initial question.

The information  you want is located in the [HttpListenerRequest.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var context = listener.GetContext();
var qry = context.Request.QueryString;
foreach(var key in qry.AllKeys)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, qry[key]);
```

Comment: I selected your answer(actually @KevinGosse 's answer :D) as correct answer. But i also noticed that if i send data in `POST` it goes to input stream. i think it is a good idea to add it to your answer(for sake of completeness) so other people having this problem can see it.

Comment: not seeing how this works.

Comment: @MikeCroteau well OP accepted the answer so it did work... In the comments he clarified what he was really trying to do and that was get informaiton from the request url.

Comment: @CSharpie "HttpListener request InputStream is always an empty stream" forgive me.. I thought this was about the stream being empty not url parsing which can be done pretty easily. Good stuff, good times. Ill keep searching for an answer.

Comment: @MikeCroteau i clarified it.